# Share resources with multi module gradle android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a doubt about the multi module project uses gradle in Android Studio.

I need to access the resource R.class on a different module. See the next example:

```
Project
   |
   |---App
   |    |---src (Main App)
   |
   |---Core
   |    |---src (Entities App + Database) - Library aar
   |
   |---CommumUI
   |    |---src (Commum user interface) - Library aar
   |
```

**App AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="org.company.project.App">
```

**Core AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="org.company.project.Core">
```

**CommumUI AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="org.company.project.CommumUI">
```

---

The building of this App is using Gradle and after this it will generate R.class in:

```
-App.buid.generated.source.r.debug.org.company.project.App.R.class
-App.buid.generated.source.r.debug.org.company.project.CommumUI.R.class
```

I tried in App project to get the resource list in CommumUI project but the object will come null.

Example:

```
//This return null
drawerLayoutList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_menu_list);

//That again return null
drawerLayoutList = (ListView) findViewById(org.company.project.CommumUI.R.id.drawer_menu_list);
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't have success:
drawerLayoutList = (ListView) findViewById(getResources().getLayout(R.layout.layout_list_drawer_menu).getIdAttributeResourceValue(R.id.commumUI_layout_list_drawer_menu));